# XML Editor that supports Relax NG

Tags: windows, text-editor, xml

I need an XML editor primarily for Windows, but OSX and X11 support would also be useful. It needs to support [Relax NG](http://www.relaxng.org/) validation. It should support auto complete of elements and attributes in a similar manner that Visual Studio does for XSD enhanced documents.